# Using Excel to total up items

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet as below.

```
Name | E-mail | Item 1 | Quantity | Item 2 | Quantity

User 1 | u1@etc | Product 5 | 1 | Product 1 | 2
User 2 | u2@etc | Product 1 | 4 | Product 5 | 2

Etc.
```

As you can see each row contains the order information but the products are in the order placed in the cart rather than a default positioning.

What I would like to do is be able to view this data as below

```
Name | E-mail | Product 1 | Product 2 

User 1 | U1@etc | 2 | 0
User 2 | U2@etc | 4 | 0
```

I have been able to use `COUNTIF` to find the number of times a product is listed but this does not take into account multiples of the items.

Edit:

If User 1 has Product 1 anywhere in their order line I would like to display the quantity etc.

Basically my source data sheet is really bad and I need to order it.

Comment: =countif(cell a #)*(cell b #)  Where cell a is the cell containing the product, and cell b is the cell containing an integer multiplier for quantity

Comment: If you put a little more into your question, you may get a few more people try to help.  As it is now, the information presented is confusing.  There is no clear correlation between the data above, and how you wish to view it below.  Present the problem clearly, and you will get clearer responses.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the multiplier as you suggested but as the products can be anywhere in the order line I cannot get it to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear how your source data is structured, however if information about both products is on the same row then it's less than ideal. If it's possible to rearrange your data to be structured like this, then it's really easy.

```
Name   | E-mail | Item      | Quantity 
User 1 | u1@etc | Product 5 | 1 
User 1 | u1@etc | Product 1 | 2 
User 2 | u2@etc | Product 1 | 4 
User 2 | u2@etc | Product 5 | 2
```

You can then use a PivotTable to summarise the results (Insert>PivotTable).

Comment: I may be able to download the data in that format.

Expect pivot table queries inbound.
Thanks

Comment: You have solved my problem old bean.

I cannot seem to give you an upvote!!

Comment: @RichArmstrong - I will upvote this answer for you (since you expressed that desire, but were not able to).  You should be able to click the hollow checkmark indicating Andy answered your issue.   Also, please ***[take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)*** to get better acquainted with SO protocols etc.

Answer (score 0):

By downloading the data in the format suggested by Andy Herd I was able to use a Pivot Table to get the result I needed.